# Refresh Sitecore index to include CD's

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I've written some code to refresh an index when an item is programmatically added to Sitecore.  Now as the live system is made up of 1 CM and 2 CD Servers I need my code to also trigger the indexing to be refreshed on the CD Servers (unfortunately my dev machine is just a single box so I can't test this fully).  I've looked online but can't find anything about this when triggering a re-index programmatically.

So the question is do I need to write code for this or does Sitecore do this by default and if I do need to write code, does anyone have ideas how I go about this.  My current code is below.

```
ISearchIndex index =  ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("GeorgeDrexler_web_index");
Sitecore.Data.Database database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");

Item item = database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/GeorgeDrexler/Global/Applications");
index.Refresh(new SitecoreIndexableItem(item));
```

My config for the index has the remotebuild strategy enabled

```
<strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild" />
```

Comment: From my point of view, there is no need to trigger a rebuild index on the CD servers. Once the user has added an item, you can publish it to the target database (web) which will then trigger the rebuild index. From the code you provided, the item will always be null since the item has been added on the CM Server (master) and is still not present on the CD Servers (web)

Answer (score 0):

As @Hishaam Namooya pointed out in his comment, publishing from master to web should trigger the web index updates out of the box, unless you've disabled something in the configurations.

Note that items won't publish unless they are in a final workflow state, so if you want a completely automated process that creates the item, updates the local index, and then immediately updates the web index, you will also need to update the workflow state to your final approved state and then trigger a publish of the item.